# MVC 5 Custom Membership Provider Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to migrate an ASP.NET application to MVC 5. The final piece to migrate is the membership provider. I am unable to configure the application to access the existing membership provider.

I started by looking at the documentation at MSDN's [Sample Membership Provider Implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa(v=vs.140).aspx). This leads me to enter the following in my Web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="MyMembershipProvider"
      type="my.namespace.MyMembershipProvider, my.package.name"
      connectionStringName="MyServiceContext"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"
      />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      name="MyRoleProvider"
      type="my.namespace.MyRoleProvider, my.package.name"
      />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

When I try to run the application, I get the following error:

```
The configuration section 'membership' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: For what it's worth, MVC 5 comes standard with Identity, which doesn't use membership providers (those are part of the older ASP.NET Membership, for which Identity is a replacement). While you can technically still work with ASP.NET Membership, it's essentially deprecated. I'm not sure what you needed a custom provider for, but you should really focus on migrating that to Identity rather than bootstrapping MVC 5 with outdated tech.

Comment: I'm working with a client that specifically wants to use the existing membership provider, so I don't really have a choice, unless I can re-map Identity to use the right tables and schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'oh!

Turns out I had put the `<membership>` tag inside the top-level `<configuration>` section, but it belongs inside `<system.web>`:

```
<configuration>
  ... stuff ...
  <system.web>
    <membership ...>
      ... stuff from question description ...
    </membership>
    <roleManager ...>
      ... stuff from question description ...
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Changing the location in the file fixed the error.

Comment: Thank you very much! This saves my life!